# Method Select of Object '_Worksheet' failed - why?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
Set mainWB = Workbooks("Copy Paste.xlsb")
Set mainWS = mainWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set testWS = mainWB.Sheets("Sheet3")

mainWS.Select
```

I keep getting an error on the last line in Excel VBA:

> "Method Select of Object '_Worksheet' failed"

Any idea why or how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Are your sheets actually named sheet1/sheet3? Is the workbook named the same?

Comment: And hence `.Select` should be avoided :) See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: Oh I didn't know select can be used only if the element is active. Great to know, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As discussed in comments, cannot select `Sheets` in VBA that are not active (or `Range` objects on them).

For example the following code

```
Sheets(1).Activate
Sheets(2).Range("A1").Select
```

will cause the error you are receiving.

In your case, it seems you are attempting to `Select` a sheet which is not active - your `mainWS` object is presumably not the `ActiveSheet` at the point you are calling this code. An easy way to test if this is happening is if you add the following to the end of your code:

```
if (ActiveSheet.Name <> mainWS.Name) then
    msgbox ("Going to crash after clicking ok!")
end if
mainWS.Select
```

Note that you can refer to the activated worksheet with the command `ActiveSheet` to either get properties or whatever other operations you are interested in doing.

This error can also happen if you have loop working thru all of the worksheets in the workbook and there are hidden sheets. Lookout for that.

---

Last, and unrelated to your specific error message, I assume you are declaring those variables somewhere and simply did not copy them here - if not I would consider using `Option Explicit` as you can often run into all sorts of issues without having `Option Explicit` at the top of your VBA code.

Comment: Excellent answer. Congratulations on the knowledge and the presentation.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the above, it is also important to note that the Delete function will not work if the worksheet's visibility is currently set to xlSheetVeryHidden

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and looked at this post for ideas on how to fix it. My issue was resolved by using "Activate" as opposed to "Select" on the line that my code was failing on. So instead of using "mainWS.Select", try using "mainWS.Activate" instead.